# jQuery trigger transition on validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm using some jQuery to do some form validation. The following is the validation script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#contact-form').validate({

    rules: {
      cf_name: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true
      },

      cf_email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },

      phone: {
        minlength: 10,
        required: true
      },

      user_pass: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true
      },

      validateSelect: {
        required: true
      },

      validateCheckbox: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      },

      validateRadio: {
        required: true
      }
    },

    focusCleanup: false,
    highlight: function(label) {
      $(label).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    },

    success: function(label) {
      label

      //.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
        .closest('.control-group').addClass('success');
    },

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      error.appendTo(element.parents('.controls'));
    }
  });
  $('.form').eq(0).find('input').eq(0).focus();
}); // end document.ready
```

On my submit button, I have this code:

```
 <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="sub" class="sub_text">
```

I'd like to make it so that when a user clicks the submit button and the form validates before it does any fading/transitioning, that it does within this code:

```
$("#sub").click(function(){

    $("#forms").fadeOut( 1000 );        
    $("#overlay1").delay(1000).fadeIn( 1000 );        

});
```

But my problem is that if a user forgets a field and then hits submit, the overlay transition happens. I'd like it to only happen when there's a 
success of validation.

How am I able to trigger the event only when it's validated?

Comment: I'm sorry I destroyed your perfect thousand. ;-)

Comment: @some-non-descript-user It's okay! I love forward progression. I'm worth more now. Thank you is in order as well. ;)

Comment: Why not just put the transitions into success callback...?

Comment: If I put it in the success callback, then when a user fills out only one field, it will trigger the transitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried calling `form.valid()` as follows:

```
$("#sub").click(function(){
    if($('#contact-form').valid()){
        $("#forms").fadeOut( 1000 );        
        $("#overlay1").delay(1000).fadeIn( 1000 ); 
    }       
});
```

[`.valid()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) checks whether given form is valid or not.

Comment: Doesn't seem to take care of the issue.

Comment: oh really...but as per plugin documentation `.valid()` returns true only if form is completely filled in proper way, I mean valid information filled.

Comment: Not sure it will work because click event will be triggered before the validation... so `if($('#contact-form').valid()){` doesn't have the correct value yet

Comment: @MathewB.- actually `.valid()` validates the form internally. So it should work.

Comment: @vijayP - works as expected! Thanks for the input. You got my vote! Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong hook. You are attaching your fadein code into "click" event of the button, means just when the user clicks the button you will execute the fadein.

Solution? quite simple, just have a look at the jqueryvalidation doc (http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate), instead of fadein in click event of the button, just do it in the validation hook.

```
$('#contact-form').validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $("#forms").fadeOut( 1000 );        
    $("#overlay1").delay(1000).fadeIn( 1000 );   
    // do other things for a valid form
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: I believe I actually tried that but couldn't get it to fire properly.